# How Can I save And reuse One hot encoding in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I'm working on a project that related to NLP. then i use One hot encode for text representation in google colab Then i fit it into LSTM.
This is my code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
voc_size=13000
onehot_repr=[one_hot(words,voc_size)for words in X1]
```

the model seem good but when i want to save it for making prediction with new text i save it using pickle:

```py
 import pickle
 with open("one_hot", "wb") as f: 
     pickle.dump(one_hot, f)
```

but when i restart the colab and load the saved one_hot again the number that represent a word is difference.

- Is there any possible way that i can save Onehot and get the same result in colab?

Because I can not save one hot encode for using another time that why i save one hot representation  as list and access it by index later:

```py
## load save model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
my_model=load_model("model9419.h5")

##load oneHot representation
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/last_model/on_hot.json', 'rb') as f:
    oneHot=json.load(f)
```

In order to predict A word i used simple array access element to find one hot representation of a words.

- Is This a correct way to make a prediction ? Is there any better way than that?
- And If I can save OneHot function how can i use in flask server?
- Also can anyone recommend word representation that is easy, can save to use in flask and better?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a one-hot dict and then convert it to pandas DataFrame and save a `.csv` of that DataFrame. ex.

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
onehot_dict = {}
voc_size = 3

for words in ['this', 'that', 'then']:
    onehot_dict[words] = one_hot(words, voc_size)

onehot_df = pd.DataFrame(onehot_dict)
onehot_df.to_csv('./onehot.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: There is no possible way that i can save onehot function directly right?